# SystemNullReferenceException или ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравствуйте!При отладке программы, выходит сообщение:

> System.NullReferenceException. Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.

и указывает на эти строки:

listView1.Items.Add("Файловая система: ").SubItems.Add(queryObj["FileSystem"].ToString());
listView1.Items.Add("Серийный номер: ").SubItems.Add(queryObj["VolumeSerialNumber"].ToString());
listView1.Items.Add("Свободное место: ").SubItems.Add(queryObj["FreeSpace"].ToString());
listView1.Items.Add("Общий размер: ").SubItems.Add(queryObj["Size"].ToString());

Вот код кнопки которое вызывает список логический дисков:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Items.Clear();
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher2 = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
               "SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk");

        foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher2.Get())
        {
            listView1.Items.Add("Диск: ").SubItems.Add(queryObj["Caption"].ToString());
            listView1.Items.Add("Значение: ").SubItems.Add(queryObj["Description"].ToString());
            listView1.Items.Add("Файловая система: ").SubItems.Add(queryObj["FileSystem"].ToString());
            listView1.Items.Add("Серийный номер: ).SubItems.Add(queryObj["VolumeSerialNumber"].ToString());
            listView1.Items.Add("Свободное место: ").SubItems.Add(queryObj["FreeSpace"].ToString());
            listView1.Items.Add("Общий размер: ").SubItems.Add(queryObj["Size"].ToString());
            listView1.Items.Add("-------------------");

        }

     }
```

Читал на форумах,что данное сообщение выскакивает когда значение равно null. Как сделать проверку или как-то изменить код?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: что делать когда я захожу в фифу 15 у меня  показывает вот такую ошибку

Comment: ссылка на объект не укзаывает  на экземпляр объекта

Answer (score 1):

Учитывая, что работа с WMI, скорее всего один из элементов в queryObj возвращает пустоту, а Вы ее к строке привести пытаетесь. String.Format может помочь, например.

Answer (score 0):

блок try-catch вам в помощь. скорее всего null при попытке обратится к словарю по несуществующему ключу.

Comment: Попробовал try с пустым catch'ем...наконец-то удалось просмотреть на чем у меня форма косячит!!!Оказывается....прога не может прочитать данные(кроме Caption и Description) в Floppy(Дискетнике) и в виртуальном диске Z,который относится к D.
Теперь вопрос в другом...как добавить в игнор диск A и Z?

Comment: Разве что на try catch и ориентироваться. Не получилось достать данные и ладно.

Comment: Написал вот так:
try {
listView1.Items.Add("Файловая система: ").SubItems.Add(queryObj["FileSystem"].ToString());
listView1.Items.Add("Общий размер: ").SubItems.Add(queryObj["Size"].ToString());
listView1.Items.Add("-------------------");
    }
     catch (Exception)
    {

Дело в том,что если например не удалось прочитать A (Floppy),то строка listView1.Items.Add("-------------------"); не выводится,а она у меня что-то вроде разделяющей.Можно ее как-то вывести?

Comment: > блок try-catch вам в помощь.

Не блок try-catch, а отладчик ему в помощь. Там все прекрасно обнаруживается.

> скорее всего null при попытке обратится к словарю по несуществующему ключу

При обращении к словарю по несуществующему ключу выбрасывается KeyNotFoundException, а у ТС NullReferenceException. Не пишите, если не знаете.

Короче, минус вам.